# Writing an R function to sort a data with a custom list of variables, possible in different directions

Tags: r, function, sorting

I have a dataset like this:

```
    dataf <- data.frame(
    Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
    Age = c(25, 30, 5, 35, 35, 15),
    Score = c(95, 88, 76, 95, 88, 76)
    )
```

I can sort this using the following:  (descending by Name and ascending by Age).  No problem.

```
  with(dataf, dataf\[order(-as.numeric(as.factor(Name)), as.numeric(as.factor(Age))), \])
```

However, I want to write a function so that I can re-use it for other datasets by different number of variables.

Say, my function has two inputs:  dataset and OrderBy
where "dataset" is the name of the dataset and
OrderBy in this format:

```
  c("var1 dir1", "var2 dir2",...)
```

In my last example, OrderBy is c("Name -", "Age +") so that the function could produce the output as

```
  with(df, df\[order(-as.numeric(as.factor(Name)), as.numeric(as.factor(Age))), \])
```

Note that there's a minus sign before the first as.numeric which is for descending by Name and then no sign for the second as.numeric which is for ascending by Age.

I actually almost made it with the following: (I am using Base R with no dplyr package)

```
 Sorting_Func <- function(df, sorting_info) {  
      print(df)  
    variable_names <- gsub("[+-]", "", sorting_info)  
    directions <- ifelse(grepl("-", sorting_info), "-", "")  
    # Create sorting expressions  
    sorting_exprs <- sapply(1:length(variable_names), function(i) {  
    expr <- paste0(directions[i], "as.numeric(as.factor(", variable_names[i], "))")  
    return(expr)  
    })  
    
    # Combine the sorting expressions into a single string  
    sorting_string <<- noquote(paste0(sorting_exprs, collapse = ", "))  
    print("sorting_string")  
    print(sorting_string)  
    
    tmp<-with(df, df[order(sorting_string), ])  
    return(df)  
    
    }  
    Sorting_Func(dataf, c("Name +", "Age -") )
```

You can see that my "sorting_string" is correct but it does NOT being evaluated/used in order() and the output is not right.
BUT if I copy the value of sorting_string into order() as below:

```
  with(dataf, dataf[order(as.numeric(as.factor(Name )), -as.numeric(as.factor(Age ))), ])
```

it works correctly.

Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

Or does anyone know if there's an existing function that I can use to achieve what I am doing here?

Example of an input data
Name Age Score
1   Alice  25    95
2     Bob  30    88
3 Charlie   5    76
4   Alice  35    95
5     Bob  35    88
6 Charlie  15    76

Sorted by Name in ascending order and by Age(within Name) in descending order.
Name Age Score
4   Alice  35    95
1   Alice  25    95
5     Bob  35    88
2     Bob  30    88
6 Charlie  15    76
3 Charlie   5    76

Comment: Even if you're not using `dplyr`, you can take inspiration. They use the handy function `desc` to sort in a descending order, which is implemented using the base function `xtfrm` - from the help page *"A generic auxiliary function that produces a numeric vector which will sort in the same order as x."* So you can simplify your code by using `xtfrm` on all your inputs - numeric, character, factor, etc, and multiplying by `-1` if the direction is `-`. That will be a lot cleaner than pasting code together as expressions.

Comment: I'd also suggest that your input format is fairly fragile. It will work nicely if your data frame only has standard column names, but if you ever have a data frame with a `+` or `-` in a column name this will break. Maybe you could use a named vector instead, calling your function like `Sorting_Func(dataf, c(Name = "-", Age = "+"))`, which can generalize to `Sorting_Func(fake_data, c("Bad+Column-Name" = "+", "Column++" = "-"))`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Taking my comments into consideration, I propose this much simpler implementation:

```
Sorting_Func = function(data, sort) {
  ## xtfrm all sorting columns to get numeric equivalents
  vars = lapply(data[names(sort)], xtfrm)

  ## multiply any descending columns by -1
  vars[sort == "-"] = lapply(vars[sort == "-"], "*", -1)

  ## sort the data
  data[do.call(what = order, args = vars), ]
}

Sorting_Func(dataf, sort = c(Name = "-", Age = "+"))
#      Name Age Score
# 3 Charlie   5    76
# 6 Charlie  15    76
# 2     Bob  30    88
# 5     Bob  35    88
# 1   Alice  25    95
# 4   Alice  35    95
```

I think the reason your implementation isn't working is because you never `eval(parse())` the pasted together expressions. But pasting together code and `eval(parse())`ing it is almost never a good idea and is rarely needed. In this case we can use `lapply` to make a `list` and `do.call` to call `order()` using the elements of the list as arguments. It's more straightforward and less bug-prone.

Using a nice built-in utility function like `xtfrm` also makes the code more robust. Standing on the shoulders of R core, this code should be nice and efficient and work for a wide variety of input data types.

Comment: The parse() did not work for me when I have a comma between the as.number terms.  And I did not know to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the function work with your desired input format using a bit of string parsing. Just be aware that this is not idiomatic R by any means, and you might be better following Gregor's suggestions. This function is longer than because of the necessary error handling that comes with allowing arbitrary string inputs, which is another reason for favoring a different input format.

That said, the following should work as long as none of the column names end with a `+` or a `-` (though it could be extended to handle those cases too). :

```r
Sorting_Func <- function(data, orderby) {
  signs <- sub('^.+(\\+|-)\\s*$', '\\1', orderby)
  if(!all(signs %in% c('+', '-'))) stop('"orderby" must end in "+" or "-"')
  signs <- c(1, -1)[match(signs, c('+', '-'))]
  cols <- trimws(sub('^(.+)\\+|-\\s*$', '\\1', orderby))
  if(!all(cols %in% names(data))) stop('All column names must be in the data')
  orders <- Map(function(x, y) xtfrm(x) * y, data[cols], signs)
  data[do.call('order', unname(orders)),]
}
```

This gives us

```r
Sorting_Func(dataf, c('Name +', 'Age -'))
#>      Name Age Score
#> 4   Alice  35    95
#> 1   Alice  25    95
#> 5     Bob  35    88
#> 2     Bob  30    88
#> 6 Charlie  15    76
#> 3 Charlie   5    76
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Good to know another way to do it.  Thanks!